# My For Loop skips my IF statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, for-loop

I wonder if anyone can help. I am making a program that will convert Text to ASCII. However, I want my program to ignore spaces. Hence, "IT WAS A" should look like this: 7384 876583 65

When I use the Step Into Feature of VB I can see that my For loop is skipping my IF statement which should be giving me my spaces.  I don't understand why. As you can probably tell, I am a beginner so any specific help would be greatly appreciated.  My code looks like this:

```
    Dim PlainText, ConvertedLetter As String
    Dim LetterToConvert As Char
    Dim AscNumber, Counter As Integer
    ConvertedLetter = ""
    PlainText = txtPlain.Text
    For Counter = 1 To Len(PlainText)
        LetterToConvert = Mid(PlainText, Counter, 1)
        If PlainText = " " Then
            ConvertedLetter = " "
        Else : AscNumber = Asc(LetterToConvert)
            ConvertedLetter = ConvertedLetter & AscNumber
        End If
    Next
    txtAscii.Text = ConvertedLetter
```

Comment: neither is there a "IF Function" nor a "Step Into Feature" in VB. There are if-STATEMENTS and DEBUGGER-functions in your IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're comparing PlainText, which is the whole string, to " ".  It would need to be:

If LetterToConvert = " " Then ....

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your quick response. This seems like the correct solution because it makes sense, but when I try it, debug shows that as soon as I get to a space in the original text, Converted Letter gets wiped. So, "IT WAS A" ends up as 65

Comment: ConvertedLetter is your output string, so you'll need to build on it as you're doing in the else case:  ConvertedLetter = ConvertedLetter & " "

Comment: Right! I think this shows the flaw in my logic. I built the ConvertedLetter = ConvertedLetter & " " as part of the Then statement and that works! Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim PlainText, ConvertedLetter As String
ConvertedLetter = ""
PlainText = "IT WAS A"
For Each c As Char In PlainText 'iterate through each character in the input
    If c <> " " Then ' check whether c is space or not
        ConvertedLetter &= Asc(c).ToString()' ascii value is taken if c<>" "
    Else
        ConvertedLetter &= " " ' c is space means add a space
    End If
Next
MsgBox(ConvertedLetter) ' display the result
```

You will get the output as

`7384 876583 65`

Comment: Yes, it does - very clever! I haven't seen anything like this before so you additional comments are extremely helpful. Thank you very much. I wonder still, where the flaw was in the original code.